# Show only first and last ticks label of x-axis plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm parsing a log file and creating a plot.

I don't need all labels on X axis. I want to display only a first one and a last one or a few of them with particular step let's say every 100.

How I can do this? I can display only first one or only last one but not both together.

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open('file.log') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    x = [int(line.split(',')[0]) for line in lines]
    my_xticks = [line.split(',')[1] for line in lines]
    y = [int(line.split(',')[2]) for line in lines]
    z = [int(line.split(',')[3]) for line in lines]

plt.xticks(x, my_xticks[0], visible=True, rotation="horizontal")
plt.xticks(x, my_xticks[-1], visible=True, rotation="horizontal")

plt.plot (x,z)
plt.plot (x,z)
plt.plot(x, y)


plt.show()
```

Thank you!

Comment: Does `plt.xticks([x.min(), x.max()])` do what you want?

Comment: It gives me an error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'min'`

Answer (score 6):

with x-ticks, you can provide a list. So you can do:

```
plt.xticks([my_xticks[0], my_xticks[-1]], visible=True, rotation="horizontal")
```

Incidentally, you can get the original ticks using:

```
my_xticks = ax.get_xticks()
```

where `ax` is your your `Axes` instance. You can even supply your own values:

```
plt.xticks(
          [my_xticks[0], my_xticks[-1]], 
          ['{:.2}'.format(my_xticks[0]), '{:.2}'.format(my_xticks[-1])]
           visible=True, rotation="horizontal")
```

etc. You can see how easily this can be generalized ...

Just remember that the tick labels refer to specific `Axes` within the figure. So ideally you should do:

```
`ax.set_xticks(..)`
```

Comment: My xticks are strings actually and they look:  9/5/2017 8:47:15 AM
So if I'm trying `lt.xticks([my_xticks[0], my_xticks[-1]], visible=True, rotation="horizontal")` I'm getting error `self._points[:, 0] = interval
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 9/5/2017 8:47:15 AM`